# How can I print the possible combinations of a list in Python?

Tags: python, loops

My list is:

```
groupA=['Russia', 'Egypt', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Uruguay']
```

So I want to print all the unique combinations of teams that will play each other:

```
Russia Vs. Egypt
Russia Vs. Saudi Arabia
Russia Vs. Uruguay
Egypt Vs. Saudi Arabia
Egypt Vs. Uruguay
Saudi Arabia Vs. Uruguay
```

Can I do this with a for loop?

Comment: You can do it with a double for loop.

Comment: Use [`itertools combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: I was bored so was happy to do this code, but don't forget that in the future you should try yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
groupA=['Russia', 'Egypt', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Uruguay']

for i in range(len(groupA)):
  for j in range(i+1, len(groupA)):
    print("{} Vs. {}".format(groupA[i], groupA[j]))
```

If you prefer using itertools:

```
from itertools import combinations

groupA=['Russia', 'Egypt', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Uruguay']

for combo in combinations(groupA, 2):
  print("{} Vs. {}".format(combo[0], combo[1]))
```

Comment: There is no need to extract the length, and if you would use the length of the list multiple times you should strongly consider a variable storing it.

Comment: @ShailynOrtiz Yes, there are multiple ways of solving this problem.

Comment: Totally agree with that, still, not to store values that are going to be used more than once is bad a practice.

Answer (score 2):

This can do the trick:

```
groupA = ['Russia', 'Egypt', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Uruguay']
for index, country in enumerate(groupA):
    for rival in groupA[index+1:]:
        print('%s vs %s'%(country, rival) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you're thinking of permutations, combinations, Cartesian products, etc, think of the `itertools` library; it's standard to Python. And if it's not in there have a look at [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> for c in combinations(groupA, 2):
...     '{} Vs. {}'.format(*c)
... 
'Russia Vs. Egypt'
'Russia Vs. Saudi Arabia'
'Russia Vs. Uruguay'
'Egypt Vs. Saudi Arabia'
'Egypt Vs. Uruguay'
'Saudi Arabia Vs. Uruguay'
```

`format` is a nice alternative for output too.

Comment: I was about to downvote for being a duplicate of my answer, but I like how you unpacked the combo, which is cleaner than my method.

Comment: Apologies! I missed the second part of your answer.

Comment: No worries--yours had an improvement.  No downvote from me!